# When I try to update and upgrade my system I get Error

Tags: upgrade

```
sudo apt upgrade 
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Calculando la actualización... Hecho
0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
6 no instalados del todo o eliminados.
Se utilizarán 0 B de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [S/n] S
Configurando linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic (5.4.0-77.86) ...
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.4.0-77-generic
Configurando initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Configurando linux-firmware (1.187.15) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-74-generic
/usr/sbin/update-initramfs: 157: mkinitramfs: not found
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-74-generic with 127.
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete linux-firmware (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado paquete linux-firmware script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 127
Configurando linux-image-5.4.0-80-generic (5.4.0-80.90) ...
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.4.0-80-generic
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depende de linux-firmware; sin embargo:
 El paquete `linux-firmware' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete linux-image-generic (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
No se escribió un informe «apport» porque el mensaje de error indica que es un mensaje de error asociado a un fallo previo.
                                                                                                                           No se escribió un informe «apport» porque el mensaje de error indica que es un mensaje de error asociado a un fallo previo.
                                                       dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de linux-generic:
 linux-generic depende de linux-image-generic (= 5.4.0.80.84); sin embargo:
 El paquete `linux-image-generic' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete linux-generic (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
Procesando disparadores para linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic (5.4.0-77.86) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-77-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-77-generic
/usr/sbin/update-initramfs: 157: mkinitramfs: not found
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-77-generic with 127.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 127
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado paquete linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                                         Procesando disparadores para initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-74-generic
/usr/sbin/update-initramfs: 157: mkinitramfs: not found
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-74-generic with 127.
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete initramfs-tools (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado paquete initramfs-tools script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 127
No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                                         Procesando disparadores para linux-image-5.4.0-80-generic (5.4.0-80.90) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-80-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-80-generic
/usr/sbin/update-initramfs: 157: mkinitramfs: not found
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-80-generic with 127.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 127
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete linux-image-5.4.0-80-generic (--configure):
 el subproceso instalado paquete linux-image-5.4.0-80-generic script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
No se escribió ningún informe «apport» porque ya se ha alcanzado el valor de «MaxReports»
                                                                                         Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-5.4.0-77-generic
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-5.4.0-80-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its right there in your output: `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs: 157: mkinitramfs: not found`

Uh-oh. Missing mkinitramfs suggests serious damage!

Let's see what package provides that application:

```
     $ which mkinitramfs
      /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs
     $ dpkg -S /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs 
      initramfs-tools-core: /usr/sbin/mkinitramfs
```

Reinstall the `initramfs-tools-core` package: `sudo apt install --reinstall initramfs-tools-core`

If apt balks again, then read your output line-by-line to find the cause. It's probably listed there.

Since your system has been mysteriously damaged, be prepared to back up your data and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Reinstalling the initramfs-tools-core package worked fine, thanks so much user535733!

Comment: Should I backup and reinstall the system anyway?